# What are some good Support or CRM services, with less aggressive 3rd party tracking?

Tags: email, crm, support-tracker

I'm a fan of Front.com, but they have a too relaxed attitude about integrating 3rd party services. Sure, that's a feature not a bug for most people, but I personally hate how this leaks user data left and right, both for internal agents and for external customers.

Is there a similar service offering shared mailbox features and workflows without too many 3rd party dependencies? (The CMS and analytics features are nice but not a must-have.) Maybe self-hosted, or just privacy-focused?